# how to convert decimal to hexadecimal in java

Tags: java

I need to convert the rest of the division by 16 to Hexadecimal. I'm using the `Integer.toHexString` method and pass the value (variable "resto") that I need to convert to hexadecimal, but the ouput value is not in hexadecimal.

```
int total = 50;
resto = total / 16;
String decimal = Integer.toHexString(resto);
System.out.println(decimal);
```

outputs `3`

Comment: `3` (base 10) == `3` (base 16). You need at least a reminder `> 9` to see a difference.

Comment: You are not using Comic Sans as your development font. I must be dreaming this. What a horrible nightmare

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Remember: the person made a conscious decision to set it to comic sans. This was not done by accident.

Comment: When asking a question, please minify your code and avoid putting picture just for showing the result. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Wow, java code in Comic Sans!  How Trumpy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using toHexString() method of Integer class.

**Exmple :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class DecimalToHexExample
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
      System.out.print("Enter a decimal number : ");
      int num =input.nextInt();

      // calling method toHexString()
      String str = Integer.toHexString(num);
      System.out.println("Decimal to hexadecimal: "+str);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a decimal number : 123
Decimal to hexadecimal: 7b
```